# Create Change Password Page

Tags: php

I have created a change password page where the 1st is condition `if ($newpassword == 0)` is working properly but else part is not working if I omit the 1st if condition the other conditions are working properly but with every refresh password field also taking blank save in DB table. The code is given below for help. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include('config.php');
//error_reporting(0);                                               
$error              = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message                     
$newpassword        = $_POST['npassword'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
if ($newpassword == 0) {
    $error = "Set a New Password!";
} else {
    if ($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE t_login SET password='$newpassword'");
    } else if ($sql) {
        $error = "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password!";
    } else {
        $error = "New Password and Confirm Password do not match. Try again!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your **UPDATE** query change password for every records are you sure you want to do that? moreover this code is not secured (SQL injection).
**EDIT**
you re wrong with yourd conditions `else if ($sql) {` it should be a **if** because here if your query success or fail , it never reach your `else if or else`.

Comment: Please try to improve your skills before coding. Your code is really bad, your `else if($sql)` can't be reach since you define `$sql` in the first `if` statement. You update password for all your users, because you don't use any `where` in your update query. Why `== 0` ? you post a default 0 value for your inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

As i've commented your conditons are wrong.

```
 if ($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) { //If you enter here you can t reach other conditions
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE t_login SET password='$newpassword'");
} else if ($sql) {
    $error = "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password!";
} else {
    $error = "New Password and Confirm Password do not match. Try again!";
}
```

You should do that

```
if ($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) {
      //HERE THERE IS AN SQL INJECTION
      $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE t_login SET password='$newpassword'");
   if ($sql) {
    $error = "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password!";
  } else {
    $error = "Mysql query error !";
  }
} else {
     $error = "New Password and Confirm Password do not match. Try again!";
}
```

You should use **prepared** statement or at least escape parameters because if your user type a **'** inside his password your code will fail !

**EDIT** I ve forgot to tell that your query change the password for every records in your table, maybe you forgot to use a **WHERE**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Most of these comments don't directly have much to do with your question, but some remarks:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include('config.php');
//error_reporting(0);
```

Please uncomment this, to get some valuable warnings!

```
$error              = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message                     
$newpassword        = $_POST['npassword'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
```

As you do not know if these are set, I would check (also to avoid a warning) if it actually exists, so something like `$newpassword = $_POST['npassword'] ?? '';`

```
if ($newpassword == 0) {
```

You are checking if it is "sort of" (the double is does type juggling for you) equal to `0`. That's quite vague. I would check if it is a valid password or not, for instance `!== ''`. This wil work really well with previous tip.

```
    $error = "Set a New Password!";
} else {
    if ($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) {
```

You can safely use `===` here.

```
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE t_login SET password='$newpassword'");
```

You probably want a `WHERE` statement in here, because this updates all rows in your table.

```
    } else if ($sql) {
```

As you defined the `$sql` in your `if` above, and this is in an `else`, it will never be true(ish) here. **This is the major bug in the code**

```
        $error = "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password!";
    } else {
        $error = "New Password and Confirm Password do not match. Try again!";
    }
}
?>
```

If you don't mix HTML and php, please omit the end-php tag.

Comment: just curious: in pure PHP script, omitting the end-php tag is a better practice?

Comment: Yup. The easiest 'argument' would be: the PSR says so (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/  , see `2.2`). More in detail, the closing tag opens you up to things like whitespace afterwards (that gets outputted, with all sorts of annoying side-effects (e.g. you start sending headers at that point) )